# Should old opinion-based questions be significantly edited?

Tags: discussion, editing, reopen-request, suggested-edits

This question [What display size and resolution is good for reading PDF in double page view?](https://superuser.com/q/775038/301042) is closed as primarily opinion-based. I attempt to edit it like this, but it says I'm editing too much. What do you think?

Also, I suggest we add some more tag: readability, x-height, screen-size.

---

The recommended distance between your eyes and screen is an arm length.

The arm length is around 60 cm (25 inch). At that distance, the x-height for easy readability is 3 mm (2 "sub-inch").

What display sizes and resolutions are the best suitable to read PDF books in double page view? Is 24" in 1900 x 1200 enough for that?

I currently have a 17" in SXGA.

Comment: It would be better if you asked your own question, within scope, that answered your question.  It's very unlikely the author will ever improve the question so it can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh, mayb, but you can't save them all. I've totally posted an [answer to a question](https://superuser.com/questions/990799/will-the-pixel-density-difference-be-visible-between-4k-and-2k-monitors-at-27-s/991823#991823) that could be POB with... a lot of detail and graphs and even a link to a spreadhseet

On the other hand, as someone who has a system designed to help with personal learning disabilities, this really feels massively opinion based. I like high pixel densities (UHD FTW) with *very* large fonts in this situation.

All 3 of your tags feel meta-taggy as well.

So, eh while you definately seem to have a personal stake here, I'm not sure that its possible to edit a 4 year old question, respecting the intent of the user without making a lot of guesses. Its possible to answer a question like that *epically* but in this case I guess the community felt otherwise.